# Default virtualhost setting for apache2?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, httpd.conf

in sites-available/default there is some default configuration.. like:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
[...]
```

and

```
Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
[...]
```

can I remove those or they are needed for some apache function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can safely remove them.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need CGI or the doc, it's safe to remove. But it might be that other programs you can install with your distribution are relying on the default CGI functionality and won't work as expected.

Comment: i will use only php so i don't need CGI. But this DOC alias i don't get what is used for

Comment: As I said, other programs you might decide to install could require the CGI functionality and will fail to work if you disable it (IIRC Smokeping does this on Debian, to name an example). It normally doesn't matter but you have to be aware of it. The doc thing is easy: You can use http://yoursite/doc to read the Apache documentation. It's not important, just a comfort function.